# Extract nth occurence in Java regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use only a regex (no additional code!) for matching the nth match? For example, I want to match the second, fourth, six, 8th, 10th, 12th  etc. occurances of \002  but skip the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, etc in the following string :

"CAR" \002 "TRAIN" \002 "BOAT" \002 "BICYCLE" \002  "HOUSE" \002 "TENNIS" \002 "BED" \002 "KITCHEN" \002 "LOVE" \002 "HAPPENIES"

Does anyone have a pure regex solution for this? I need this because I can't change the code that uses the regex, but I can provide a regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: About possibility, yes it is possible, I can think of a DFA that does this pretty easily (matches modulus n). I'll wait for some wizards to come up with interesting RegExps for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you just double up the regex:

```
\002[^\002]*(\002)
```

To generally match every nth occurrence of a particular string, you can use `{}`:

```
(?:\002[^\002]*){n-1}(\002)
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question *how* the regex is being tested. This solution assumes it's used in a `while(matcher.find())` type loop.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you needed to match the single character `\002` or the sequence backslash-zero-zero-two. Anyway, [here's](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F%3Ax[^x]*%29{2}%28x%29&input=x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x%20x) an example using the letter `x` instead.